# In "Does it matter how large the selection is that you bookmark? ", how to understand the part "that you bookmark"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

There is a sentence:

> Does it matter how large the selection **is** that you bookmark?

I know it refers to **how large the selection is**, but I can't understand why **that you bookmark** can be added after **is**.

Can you tell me how to distinguish the composition of this sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward way of composing that sentence would be:

> Does it matter how large the **selection** [that you bookmark] is?

In this version, it's clearer that the relative clause "that you bookmark" modifies "selection". The original sentence has exactly the same underlying structure, just arranged differently.

Relative clauses refer to nouns that come before them. This noun that it refers to is called a "*referent*". Generally speaking the closer together the referent and relative clause are, and the fewer nouns there are in between them, the easier it is to understand what the relative clause refers to. But there's no rule that says one must immediately follow the other.

This sentence is poor style, but grammatically correct, and a native speaker might say it:

> I chatted with a **bunch** of other students after the prof had given us our homework and left [who wanted to form a study group].

Here, "bunch" is the referent, and "who wanted to form a study group" is the relative clause that modifies it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still confuse. "Does it matter how large the **selection** [that you bookmark] is?" Why can we use this style: noun + that + noun? In my memory, I only saw this style: noun + that + noun + be/verb. So, why not use this style:  "Does it matter how large the **selection** [that you bookmark contains] is?

Comment: @Y.zeng They're both correct. It's a matter of personal preference which you choose. Personally, I prefer your original sentence to my rearrangement of it because I don't like ending sentences with "is" if I can avoid it

Comment: May you tell me when can I omit **contains** in the "selection [that you bookmark **contains**]"? Is there a knowlenge?

Comment: @Y.zeng That sounds like a separate question, and the comment section isn't the place for that. Please ask about "contains" in a new question